# Errors building project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, vtk, itk

For my work I want to implement an Add-on for the open source project "ITK-Snap". 
Using the official [guide](http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Documentation.BuildingITK-SNAP), I built ITK,VTK with CMake and installed them as well as Qt5.6. [image: ITK-VTK CMake][image]
After then using CMake to build ITK-Snap and trying to build the project with Visual Studio 2017 will lead to about 150 Errors, most of them include a submodule used in ITK-Snap named `greedy`. I'll include all of the different error codes + messages in the screenshots, but keep in mind that many errors occur many times.

[image: Errors]

Maybe I have some error in the CMake settings? 
Thanks for Your help.

Comment: Misconfiguration of CMake is the most probable. Show us log with the very first errors. Also check, if all the libraries have the same values of CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 of those projects have a directory called CMake in their source code. Deciding to make it also the build directory is a poor choice at best. Two good choices would be `C:/FWF/ITK/build` and `C:/FWF/ITK-build`. The second choice is even better because it allows searching only the source directory, and excluding the bigger build directory. Same logic holds for VTK and ITK-Snap.

Your errors are coming from ITK-Snap's git [sub-module](https://sourceforge.net/p/itk-snap/src/ci/master/tree/.gitmodules) called `greedy`. The most likely reason is that version of `greedy` is mismatched to the version of ITK-Snap. Perhaps the author forgot to update the version of `greedy` in main repository? Try a few different versions of `greedy` including the latest stable version of everything. If that does not help I suggest to ask on ITK-Snap's [mailing list](http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=MailingLists.MailingLists).

Comment: Building everything in seperate directories worked for me.

Comment: ok right now I'm building it again and it will show the errors again, I haven't changed anything.